# How to add milliseconds to this javascript reverse count down timer counter

Tags: javascript, timer, counter, countdown, countdowntimer

```
numberOfSeconds=1*60,
r=document.getElementById('clock');
var t = setInterval(function(){
numberOfSeconds--;
var minutes=Math.floor(numberOfSeconds/60),seconds=(numberOfSeconds%60)+'';
r.textContent='Registration closes in '+minutes+':'+(seconds.length>1?'':'0')+seconds;
if (numberOfSeconds <= 0) {
clearInterval(t);
alert('boom');
}
},1000);
```

html section

```
<div id="clock"></div>
```

how i can add milliseconds to this reverse count down timer/counter script.

i want it like 00:00:00 <== milliseconds in last.

```
}},1000 / 20);
```

However above little change in last of script made seconds into milliseconds but i can't figure out how i can adjust it with seconds like MM:SS:MS 00:00:00

Any Help will be appreciated..!

Comment: You can use http://momentjs.com/ library to deal with time parsing. To show alert -> alert('something');

Answer (score 0):

That *setInterval will have to be set to 1* (ms), if you need to see the milliseconds.  1000ms = 1s. So I believe MM:SS:MS would look more like 00:00:000.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it's possible. i did a test and the results show that js cannot be as fast to set 1millisecond to setInterval. setting it to 1ms - 15ms will output the same results. 
normaly the code below should work the way you wanted.

```js
var m = 60*1000, r = document.getElementById("clock");
        var t = setInterval(function () {
            m--;
            var min = Math.floor(m / 60000),
            sec = Math.floor((m % 60000) / 1000);
            mil = (m % 60000) % 1000; r.innerHTML = min + ":" + sec + ":" + mil;}, 1)
```

Maybe the problem comes from my computer (maybe it is slow).
if you ever want the test script, tell it in comment so i will give it to you in order you'll test it by yourself